# Migration of existing forcehybrid apps from AngularJS to Angular

Tags: mobilesdk, angularjs, angular, cordova, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

We have an existing app running on `Cordova 9.0.0`, `forcehybrid CLI 7.3.0` and `Salesforce SDK 7.2.0` which is built using `AngularJS v1.7.5`.

As it is known that `AngularJS` is deprecated and is not actively supported (`v1.7.x` is in LTS till July 2021), we have to migrate our existing apps to the `Angular` latest version (`v9.0.0`).

We are trying to figure out a recommended approach for creating a Cordova project with Angular and Salesforce Mobile JS SDK.

Below is one such approach which doesn't mention anything about Salesforce Mobile SDK integration in the project:

https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79

Can you please guide us on the recommended approach to migrate our existing AngularJS apps to Angular (Typescript) based app using Salesforce Mobile SDK?

Should we still use forcehybrid CLI for creating the starter project?